# Turbolinks and Drift Chat

Tags: turbolinks, ruby-on-rails-6, drift

I am using the Drift chat widget but it doesn't reload after the first page view. 
Widget code is loaded in  and I have set a reload function at each turbolinks reload

```
<head>
<script>

    "use strict";


      !function() {
        var t = window.driftt = window.drift = window.driftt || [];
        if (!t.init) {
          if (t.invoked) return void (window.console && console.error && console.error("Drift snippet included twice."));
          t.invoked = !0, t.methods = [ "identify", "config", "track", "reset", "debug", "show", "ping", "page", "hide", "off", "on" ],
          t.factory = function(e) {
            return function() {
              var n = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
              return n.unshift(e), t.push(n), t;
            };
          }, t.methods.forEach(function(e) {
            t[e] = t.factory(e);
          }), t.load = function(t) {
            var e = 3e5, n = Math.ceil(new Date() / e) * e, o = document.createElement("script");
            o.type = "text/javascript", o.async = !0, o.crossorigin = "anonymous", o.src = "https://js.driftt.com/include/" + n + "/" + t + ".js";
            var i = document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
            i.parentNode.insertBefore(o, i);
          };
        }
      }();
      drift.SNIPPET_VERSION = '0.3.1';
      drift.load('XXXXXXXXXXX');
      drift.config({
        enableWelcomeMessage: false,
        locale: "<%=I18n.locale%>"
      });

      $(document).on("turbolinks:load", function(event) {
        drift.on('ready',function(api){
           drift.api.widget.show() <------- problem is here (?)
        })
      })

      drift.on('ready',function(api){

        console.log("Drift is ready")

        $('.drift-open-chat').on('click', function(e){
          api.widget.show()
          api.sidebar.open()
          e.preventDefault();
        })


        <% if current_user %>
          drift.api.setUserAttributes({
            user_id: <%=current_user.id%>,
            email: "<%=current_user.email%>"          
          })
        <% end %>

      })




    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Drift expects the every navigation to be a full page reload, something that Turbolinks breaks. To fix the problem, you must add two permanent elements to your layout file. This will cause tubolinks to persist the chat widget from one body swap to another.

```
<div id="drift-frame-chat" class="drift-conductor-item drift-frame-chat" data-turbolinks-permanent></div>
<div id="drift-frame-controller" class="drift-conductor-item drift-frame-controller" data-turbolinks-permanent></div>
```

**EDIT: It's been changed again.**
Use the code below when changing pages to get it working correctly:

```
document.addEventListener('turbolinks:load',
  () => {
    if (window.drift.ready) {
      window.drift.unload();
      window.drift.load('{YOUR_EMBED_ID}');
    }
  })
```